# Using "Import" AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, autocomplete

I´d like to know.

What exactly does 'import'?

I´m thinking about to use a flash component with this 'import':

```
 //import the required data class
import fl.data.DataProvider;
//import the AutoComplete class
import com.yahoo.astra.fl.controls.AutoComplete;
```

I mean, I don´t have those folders in my app main folder.

Is it importing from web?

If yes, is it safe? If server is shut down, will the app, that uses those classes, crash?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not importing from the web. `import` is resolved at compile-time.  There are many built-in modules you can import, like flash.* and fl.*. `com.yahoo.astra.fl.controls.AutoComplete` is certainly *not* built-in, though, and must exist *somewhere* on your drive during compilation. The compiler looks in a couple places, but the most common place to put custom stuff is in the same folder as your project.

Comment: So it´s not dangerous to use it?
If Yahoo server is shut down, will the app still work?

Comment: I mean, I can´t see the folders. If I export the swf and upload the files to a server. Is it going to work? Without uploading the class?

Comment: Short answer, it isn't importing anything if you don't have those folders. Read my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the import statement you can include certain ActionScript classes in your application, which then will be compiled in your SWF file. If you use strict syntax and you try to use a Class member that is not imported, the compiler will tell you about it. Otherwise your app will still work.

The imported AS classes must be added to your library path, or src path when working on an ActionScript project. You can't import online files.

Rob

Answer (score 2):

I am almost completely certain that import does not get anything from the web. I use imports for a complex game core I wrote. Imports can either import from a component of the Flash platform, or from your own classes. When the .swf is compiled, those classes are pulled in and compiled as part of the project.

In order to import something other than from the Flash platform, you WILL need to have the folders in your project. For example, I have gradua.as at trailcrest/gradua/gradua.as, and that trailcrest folder is located in the same directory as my Flash project (.fla). At the top of my gradua.as class, I have the following:

```
package trailcrest.gradua
{
    public class gradua
```

Then, I can import gradua for use in my main .fla's document class (named osr.as, btw)...

```
import trailcrest.gradua.gradua;
public static var Gradua:gradua = new gradua();
```

And I can access its functions (such as my Score function) from anywhere in my project...

```
osr.Gradua.Score(true);
```

Again, to restate...to the best of my knowledge, you CANNOT import from the web this way. Flash is going to look for the file path com/yahoo/astra/fl/controls/AutoComplete.as in your project directory...and in a couple other places on your computer, tho I'm not sure where atm...