# How to install Cory's CollisionDetectionKit

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, collision-detection, flashdevelop

I am having trouble installing/downloading Cory's CollisionDetectionKit. It comes with folders nestled within folders with three `.as` files at the end. Where should I put these files/ the folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `com` folder in the **same directory** as your `.fla` and in your code, at the top, use `import` to import the files:

```
import com.coreyoneil.collision.*;
```

Looking at the files, it looks as you can now call functions like:

```
CDK.addItem(), CDK.removeItem(), CollisionGroup.checkCollisions(), CollisionList.swapTarget(target), CollisionList.checkCollisions(), etc.
```

[Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844512/using-import-as3)

Comment: The .fla as in the project I'm working on? Even if i have them in a separate folder on my desktop?

Comment: @user2789610 Yes, technically where the code is

Comment: @user2789610 Tell me if it works out.  If it does, accept this answer, please.